# Foreign key use with user model upload

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, models

These are my models and one user can upload multiple videos but one video belongs only to one user. How do I use the foreign key concept over here? When I add a user, does this automatically add a username in the Video model? If not, how do I do that? I'm very new to django over here

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email_id=models.CharField(max_length=30, default='NULL')
    profile_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepics/%Y/%m/%d/',default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

class Video(models.Model):
    username=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    video=models.FileField(upload_to='videos/%Y/%m/%d/',default='')
    videotitle=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video
```

Comment: Take a look at this! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topic…

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Video(models.Model):
    ...
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

> Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will return the currently active User model – the custom User model if one is specified, or User otherwise.

More info can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Answer (score 0):

Not, it won't do it automatically -- and how would it do that. You need to pass user. Also you definitely don't want to add a username, but a reference to a User object. This is misleading in the code as you have a "username" in the Video class, which acutally is not just a name (string), but a ForeignKey -- a reference to an object User when adding the new video. So what you need to do when adding a video is something along the lines of:

```
def add_new_video(username, filename, title):
    owner = User.objects.get(username=username)
    newvid = Video(username=owner, video=filename, videotitle=title)
    newvid.save()
```

assuming that likes and dislikes will be added later on...

Comment: ok... reading the post from @Niels, it is possible to fill it out automatically if you want to add the currently logged in user... but that was not part of the question ...

Comment: Thanks. Got it. The video is now being uploaded properly